# c++ - bluetooth over winsock, how to remove byte order mark

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, winsock2

I want to transfer some stringdata from my Android-device to my Windows-Laptop via Bluetooth.
Using the codesample for bluetooth with winsock2 provided by [Microsoft](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296/sourcecode?fileId=42913&pathId=2083610005) I was able to transfer data using the below code. Unfortunately I receive a byte order mark at the beginning of the string I send. Of course, I could simply remove the first four bytes, but that seems a little bit dirty to me. Is there any other option I could use?

C++-code for receiving (slightly modified for better readability -> no error handling no comment, etc.)

```
ClientSocket = accept(LocalSocket, NULL, NULL);  
BOOL bContinue = TRUE; 
pszDataBuffer = (char *)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 
                                  HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 
                                  CXN_TRANSFER_DATA_LENGTH); 
pszDataBufferIndex = pszDataBuffer; 
uiTotalLengthReceived = 0; 
while ( bContinue && (uiTotalLengthReceived < CXN_TRANSFER_DATA_LENGTH) ) { 
    iLengthReceived = recv(ClientSocket, 
                           (char *)pszDataBufferIndex, 
                           (CXN_TRANSFER_DATA_LENGTH - uiTotalLengthReceived), 
                           0); 

    switch ( iLengthReceived ) { 
    case 0: // socket connection has been closed gracefully 
        bContinue = FALSE; 
        break; 

    case SOCKET_ERROR: 
        wprintf(L"=CRITICAL= | recv() call failed. WSAGetLastError=[%d]\n", WSAGetLastError()); 
        bContinue = FALSE; 
        ulRetCode = CXN_ERROR; 
        break; 

    default:  
        pszDataBufferIndex += iLengthReceived; 
        uiTotalLengthReceived += iLengthReceived; 
        break; 
    } 
} 
if ( CXN_SUCCESS == ulRetCode ) { 
    pszDataBuffer[uiTotalLengthReceived] = '\0';
    wprintf(L"*INFO* | Received following data string from remote device:\n%s\n", (wchar_t *)pszDataBuffer); 
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;                  
}
```

Android-code for sending:

```
OutputStream socketOutpuStream = socket.getOutputStream();
socketOutputStream.write(dataString.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_16));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel quite stupid right now. Working in homogeneous java environments for some years made me completely forget that java sets the byte order mark when calling getBytes() with a unicodecharset as parameter.
After changing `dataString.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_16)` to `dataString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)` (windows is little endian) on the android side everything works as expected.